# I keep coming up with the wrong calculation when using the vincenty formula

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry

I'm trying to use the formula from (www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to return a destination point giving a starting point, distance and bearing. These are my values:

```
int radius_km = 6371;
double d = 74.02;
double st_lat = 39.4450;
st_lat = Math.toRadians(st_lat); 
double bearing = 106.1607;
bearing = Math.toRadians(bearing);

double end_lat = Math.asin( Math.sin(st_lat)*Math.cos(d/radius_km) +
          Math.cos(st_lat)*Math.sin(d/radius_km)*Math.cos
          (bearing) );

end_lat = Math.toDegrees(end_lat);
```

When I enter the d, st_lat and bearing at the website, I get this: 39°33′28″N.
When I use the above code (that I copied from the website) I get this: 39.25679699255662.

I looked around more and somebody said the division may not return the decimal amount, so I replaced the division with:

```
BigDecimal distance = new BigDecimal("74.02");
BigDecimal strradius = new BigDecimal("6371");
BigDecimal d2 = distance.divide(strradius, 6, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
double d = d2.doubleValue();
```

and changed the formula to:

```
end_lat=Math.asin(Math.sin(st_lat)*
 Math.cos(d)+Math.cos(st_lat)*Math.sin(d)*Math.cos(bearing));
```

The answer I get now is 39.25680143864117.
I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm not able to go through each step of the calculation to see where I'm off at. Does anybody have step-by-step instructions on how to do this? I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: Small distances won't be very accurate if you use the trig functions

Comment: What would you suggest it be?

Comment: @Dave: Are you confused by `float` vs. `double` vs. `int`?  Is that the question?  Why isn't all of this float?  Why is radius an integer?

Comment: I have not had much experience with different types. If they should all be float then I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Dave: "If they should all be float"?  This is a question you must answer by studying the algorithm and thinking through what the types mean and creating a proper design.  I'm just asking why you chose `int`?  I don't understand the design in your example code.  I'm not answering anything.  I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: I chose it based on my limited knowledge of type. The radius is a whole number so I went with integer type.

Comment: @Dave: "my limited knowledge of type" is part of the problem.  You should perhaps expand your limited knowledge and not guess randomly at type choices.

Comment: I agree with you on that. I will work to understand the different types better so I can apply them appropriately. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are doing the correct conversion from minutes/seconds to decimals?

There are 60 minutes in a degree, 60 seconds in a minute.  If the starting latitude is 39.4450; assuming that positive means north of the equator.  If the bearing of 106.1607 is assumed to be measured from north going clockwise; would mean you are traveling southeast.

You said the website is telling you the answer is 39°33′28″N, but if I convert this to decimal, that is equal to 39+(33+28/60)/60 = 39.5578.  This result is greater than your starting point, i.e., you are traveling southeast, but ending up north of your point.

I haven't looked at the math in your code yet, but off hand I would say your problem lies in the conversion from minutes/seconds to decimals and back.

Comment: Given that the original poster hasn't done any conversion to minutes/seconds are you suggesting that the problem is that the website he is using as a reference is wrong? I can't load up that website myself so I can't actually check what its doing...

Comment: I suspect the website is taking input as minutes/seconds and he is entering it as decimal... 39°44′50″N, instead of 39°26′42″N

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Definitely possible. I wondered myself if it was something like the website truncating inputs to integers or something like that on the bearign and distance.

Comment: I'm not suggesting in any way that the website is incorrect. I'm going on the assumption that the website is correct and I'm doing it wrong. What I'm asking is if somebody knows the step by step process. I did not convert it to decimals because I did not see it being done and that is the point of my question: It definitely seems like I'm omitting at least one conversion/calculation.

Comment: Sorry I misread the comment about the website being incorrect.

Comment: I see how you converted 39 26 42 into 39 44 50. What is the formula to reverse it?

Comment: I was able to do the conversions suggested and I am now arriving at the answer that matches the website answer. Thank you for your help.